# How to check specific features through code?

Tags: android, uses-feature

Here is the  `<uses-feature>` and `<uses-permission>` specified in manifest file for my Android application

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I know that  are used for specifying required hardware/software features for the application.Also this tag filters our application in Google Play.My application did not show for some devices including tablets too. I have some doubts.

1. Does anything happen if we specify `<uses-permission>` without using  `<uses-feature>`?For eg: Use the permissions `CALL_PHONE,MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` etc... without specifying hardware feature `android.hardware.telephony`
2. My application fired the following receivers when click o two buttons.
   How can i check for these features from code?

   android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" 
    action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"

Thanks in Advance

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12644377/983741

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(1) You need to define the both `<uses-permission />` and `<uses-feature />` and then set `android:required="false"` for that feature. For instance

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
```

In this case you get permissions but the feature is not required and you can check whether it is available in your code. For that

(2) you should use [`PackageManager.hasSystemFeature()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature%28java.lang.String%29) method. For instance

```
    PackageManager mgr = context.getPackageManager();
    boolean hasTelephony = mgr.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);
```

Comment: What happens when i set required="false" for these features and did not check it from code? Does this code crash if the feature not found?

Comment: It depends. It will crash if corresponding manger or implementation will be missing on the device. If you just have a BroadcastReceiver, then it won't be notified, but it won't crash either.