# Uses-Permission vs Uses-Feature

Tags: java, android

I've seen many specific cases of people asking and people explaining the difference between the two but I can't and don't seem to understand the general difference. Are the two synonymous? Does one imply the other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643825/androidmanifest-xml-implied-vs-explicit-permissions-uses-feature-vs-uses-permi

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> Are the two synonymous?

No. `<uses-permission>` says "hey, Android (and associated distribution channels), please ask the user to allow me to do X". `<uses-feature>` says "hey, Android (and associated distribution channels), I am interested in running on hardware with feature Y".

`<uses-feature>` may filter you out of the Play Store (and other channels), if the hardware does not meet your requirements, but the user doesn't get involved.

> Does one imply the other?

Sometimes. [If you request certain permissions, like `CAMERA`, Android assumes by default that you need the corresponding hardware](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions). You can use `<uses-feature>` and `android:required="false"` to override that default behavior, if needed.

Comment: @CommonsWare can I use <uses-feature> with the "com.android.vending.billing"?

Comment: @OmarAbdan: That is not listed [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html), so I would assume the answer is "no".

Comment: @CommonsWare so, is uses_feature is enough in case the feature is listed there? like CAMERA?

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat: Sorry, but I do not understand your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare like if I want to access camera from within my app, if I used `<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>` will that be enough for accessing it? or should I include also  `<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` .

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat: Personally, I recommend always including the `<uses-permission>` element, as it makes it obvious to the people maintaining the app that you are requesting the permission. However, in the particular case of `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>`, AFAIK you could skip the `<uses-permission>` element, and Android will assume that you meant to ask for it anyway.

Answer (score 15):

It is recommended to use `<uses-feature>` along with `<uses-permission>`. Every feature of your app needs `<uses-feature>` with attribute `android:required="false"` **if your app can work without it**. The reason for this is that Google Play filters out applications which have features implemented programmatically but not supported by hardware, and as a result you don't see them there.

For example, among other several permissions your app has a permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`. If there is a device which doesn't have GPS capability, then this device will not see this app in Google Play. If your app completely functional without a GPS Connection, then the solution would be to add:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false"/> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false"/>
```

Thus, as it is already mentioned by @CommonsWare, `<uses-feature>` overrides the default behaviour of `<uses-permission>`

Comment: Thanks, this helped a ton when troubleshooting why Amazon tablets weren't compatible with my app!