# Can I define FEATURE without defining PERMISSION, What is exact difference between both?

Tags: android

I wanted to know the difference between "permission" and "feature"

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Is it required to declare LOCATION permission before accessing below two FEATURES?

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uses-Permission vs Uses-Feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079449/uses-permission-vs-uses-feature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it will clear your thinking and it will help you !

> Are the two synonymous?

No. `<uses-permission>` says **"hey, Android (and associated distribution channels), please ask the user to allow me to do X"**. `<uses-feature>` says **"hey, Android (and associated distribution channels), I am interested in running on hardware with feature Y"**.

`<uses-feature>` may filter you out of the Play Store (and other channels), if the hardware does not meet your requirements, but the user doesn't get involved.

> Does one imply the other?

Sometimes. [If you request certain permissions, like CAMERA, Android assumes by default that you need the corresponding hardware.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions) You can use `<uses-feature>` and `android:required="false"` to override that default behavior, if needed.

Comment: nice copy-paste from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079449/uses-permission-vs-uses-feature

Answer (score 2):

`uses-permission` goal is to ask a user to allow you to perform some action.

`uses-feature` goal is to show that you want to run your app on hardware with specific feature.

`uses-feature` may filter you out of the Play Store (and other channels), if the hardware does not meet your requirements, but the user doesn't get involved.

Regarding your question. It is pointless to define permission for location withou declaring feature for it, because you can't access device's location if his hardware can't do it.