# How to make compatibility in android app

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-camera2

I'm beginner Android Developer. I have built simple android app which use flash from camera. I have built this app for API less then 23 and it was working, but then I change camera library to camera2 and rebuilt app. But my issue - my app is compatible just for about 5k devices. Old version is compatible for about 13K devices. I think I confused with permission or feature. Please give an advice what is wrong.

Please see my manifest file below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>

<application...>
```

And build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com..."
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 24
    versionName "2.3"
}   
}
```

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28079486/6455501

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because the higher the targeted api the less compatible number of devices.

If it is just the flashlight then I would keep using the old version, well at least that is what I have done with my flashlight app.

Remember to ask permission for sdk 23 and higher.

Comment: I can't use old version, because I'm using camera library which is deprecated on version above API22

Comment: If you want more users you have to use the deprecated api

Answer (score 0):

minsdkversion must be low. set around 21 to get more device compatible. it supports above lollipop devices if u use 21.

Comment: Why you capitalized the sentence . Please use proper formatting to answer a question .

Comment: I can't. Camera library supported up to 22 and camera2 above 22

Comment: @VSirchenko you can use both the libraries and you can call the method by comparing the version. for your help this the way to achieve this. if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    // Do something for lollipop and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop
}

Answer (score 0):

you can use both the libraries and you can call the method by comparing the version. for your help this the way to achieve this.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    // Do something for lollipop and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop
}
```