# Android app is supported by 0 devices when App is live on Play Store

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-console, android-screen-support

I have launched my app on Play Store and when I checked my live app it is incompatible with all android devices. I checked Play Store console. It shows me 0 supported devices. I don't know why my app do not support any device.

Manifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="zkm.com.zkm">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">

</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Utils.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity
        android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Activity.Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Activity.WelcomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Activity.CarerSeekerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"

        />
    <activity
        android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Activity.SeekerAdditionalDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Activity.CareSeekerRegistrationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Activity.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Activity.HelpActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Activity.CareProviderHelpActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Activity.CareProviderActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Activity.ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />

    <activity
        android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Activity.ConfirmPasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />

    <activity
        android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Activity.SearchCareProfileSeekerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" />


    <activity
        android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Activity.SearchPackageCareProviderActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" />

    <!-- Firebase Notifications -->
    <service
        android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="zkm.com.zkm.Notification.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <!-- ./Firebase Notifications -->


    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="zkm.com.zkm.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>


</application>
```

App's Gradle:

```
      apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
      compileSdkVersion 28
      defaultConfig {
         applicationId "zkm.com.zkm"
         minSdkVersion 19
         targetSdkVersion 28
         versionCode 2
         versionName "1.0.1"
         testInstrumentationRunner 
         "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

     }
    buildTypes {
        release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- 
           android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
  }

lintOptions {
      checkReleaseBuilds false
       // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for 
    errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
  }
 }

dependencies {

  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.emanzanoaxa:RippleEffect:52ea2a0ab6'


testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:8.7.0'
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.0'

repositories {

    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
         }
       }
  }
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please check my manifest and let me know what I have done wrong.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong in your manifest file. Maybe you left something while publishing app in playstore.I recommend you go through all fields of playstore before publishing app

Comment: @bhavyajoshi   I have done everything and completed all the things.

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of message ?
You can also email google developer support for this issue and asking the reasons.

Comment: I think your problem is well described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079449/uses-permission-vs-uses-feature)

Comment: @bhavyajoshi . there is no such message no play store console even I have mailed them several times to know the issue

Comment: I don't believe a single device has such a feature `<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

Answer (score 4):

Nothing seems to be wrong particularly but I doubt this line:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Because I think it should be:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

And that you have already included in your Android manifest file, so just remove this skeptical line and see what happens!

Comment: I agree with your answer

Comment: I have added both permission and feature because camera does not work for some devices if not used "uses-feature"

Comment: @mobiledeveloper that's weird, I haven't seen such case yet and I don't believe this would be the case because that doesn't make any sense to use permission value in uses-feature tag.

Comment: @PratikButaniAndroidDev haha yeah found some time and so thought to visit you all and say Hi :)

Comment: Waiting for 100k :) @PareshMayani

Answer (score 0):

As i've mentioned in comments, nothing seems to be wrong in your files.
You can raise query through google developer's account asking for specific reason ,why you are seeing that error message.

I would also recommend you go through all the details filled in playstore before publishing app.

Also, it would be helpful if you can post the screenshot of google developer publishing console

Comment: there is no such message no play store console even I have mailed them several times to know the issue

Answer (score -1):

you must be required false. because not all device provides camera hardware.

```
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera"android:required="false"/>
```